# try to modify before display put in variable, but error print(record['recommendation']) become temp=record['recommendation']

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, fastapi

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(
  "neo4j://34.201.9.108:7687",
  auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "chart-certifications-bottom"))

cypher_query = '''
MATCH (m:Movie {title:$movie})<-[:RATED]-(u:User)-[:RATED]->(rec:Movie)
RETURN distinct rec.title AS recommendation LIMIT 20
'''

with driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
  results = session.read_transaction(
    lambda tx: tx.run(cypher_query,
                      movie="Crimson Tide").data())
  for record in results:
    print(record['recommendation']) #<----------------------- OK
driver.close()
```

try to modify before display put in variable, but error
print(record['recommendation']) become temp=record['recommendation']

```
@app.get("/neo4j")
def graph_db():
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver(
    "neo4j://34.201.9.108:7687",
    auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "chart-certifications-bottom"))

    cypher_query = '''
    MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 25
    '''
    with driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
        results = session.read_transaction(
        lambda tx: tx.run(cypher_query,
                        movie="Crimson Tide").data())
    data=[]                    
    for record in results:
        temp=record['recommendation'] #<-----------------------error
        data.append(temp)
    result=data
    driver.close()
    return{"Result ":result}
```

Comment: The cypher_query isn't the same.  What does ```record``` look like before the error?

Comment: Please include that in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: "The cypher_query isn't the same". That right.... I'm so Sorry

Answer (score 0):

When you replaced your query to

```
MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

You are returning nodes of 25 Person and the column recommendation does not exists.

```
 temp=record['recommendation']
```

Make sure that the result set that your query is returning is the same with the column name that you are accessing.